# Regular expression to count some characters

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'v got file with lines build like that

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss * -start *
yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss * -end *
```

Can anyone help me build regexp to count most common "-mm-ss" and print them sorted? by * i mean any string

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{split($2,a,"-");b[a[2]"-"a[3]]++}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
yyyy-mm-dd hh-11-55 * -start *
yyyy-mm-dd hh-11-55 * -start *
yyyy-mm-dd hh-12-22 * -end *  
> nawk '{split($2,a,"-");b[a[2]"-"a[3]]++}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' temp
12-22 1
11-55 2
>
```

below is the command which prints all hh-mm first and then all mm-ss:

```
awk '{split($2,a,"-");b[a[2]"-"a[3]]++;c[a[1]"-"a[2]]++}END{for(i in c)print i,c[i];for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' your_file
```

Comment: by * i mean any string anyway thanks i also wanna make it to print first all starts hh-mm and then all ends hh-mm

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tmp
yyyy-mm-dd hh-11-55 * -start *
yyyy-mm-dd hh-11-55 * -start *
yyyy-mm-dd hh-12-22 * -end *  

$ cut -c 15-19 tmp | sort | uniq -c
      2 11-55
      1 12-22
```